# Python for loops and manipulations

Tags: python

Hey guys I was scoping out the code from another post here on stackoverflow and I noticed something about a "for loop". If you change the list using "pop" or "remove" it messes up the indexes of that internal loop. It will skip whole items if you pop/remove item from the list. The way I got around it was to actually make a copy of the list to use in the "for loop" while I manipulated the other list. Im new to python.

I added to his list. My program removes anyone weighing over 180 or anyone named joe. At first I just used d_list when I notice this issue. Then I just "temp_list = d_list" which I thought made a separate copy but I guess doesn't. Then I used the copy attribute for list to make it work. This way I would not manipulate the list the "for loop" was using.

My question is, is that normal and did I go about it right to fix it? To me if the data was huge you would not want to make a copy of data. The other alternative I come up with is using a while loop instead of the outer for loop.

```
d_list = [ {'id':1, 'Name': 'Hannah', 'weight':150}, {'id':2, 'Name':'Andrew', 'weight':200}, {'id':3, 'Name':'Joe', 'weight':180},
           {'id':4, 'Name':'Joe', 'weight':180}, {'id':5, 'Name':'Steve', 'weight':200}, {'id':6, 'Name':'Joe', 'weight':180},
           {'id':7, 'Name':'George', 'weight':180}]

temp_list = d_list
#temp_list = d_list.copy()
print(d_list)
i = 0
for item in temp_list: # may make a while loop
    print(item, "i = ", i, end="[")
    for k, v in item.items():
        print(end="*")
        if (k == "weight") and (v > 180):
            d_list.pop(i)
            print('^popped^', i, end="")  # <-- pop but you need an index
            i -= 1
        elif (k == "Name") and (v == "Joe"):
            d_list.remove(item)          # <-- remove just uses item to find and remove
            print("^removed^", i, end="")
            i -= 1
    i += 1
    print("]")
print(d_list)
print("i = ", i)
```

Comment: It's not usual, because `pop` and `remove` on lists are usually not used in efficient solutions. Usually for simple things, you would use a list comprehension. For more complicated things, a for loop as in @alexis answer. It's counter-intuitive to beginners, but it's usually more efficient to make a brand new list than to modify one in place this way.

Answer (score 1):

Because of the problems you identified, this kind of thing is best done by making a new list of the qualifying elements. Also, it's silly to scan all keys and values; dictionaries are meant to be used by looking up the key:

```
newlist = []
for item in d_list:
    if item["weight"] <= 180 and item["Name"] != "Joe":
        newlist.append(item)
```

You can then free up the old list if you're worried about "wasting" space:

```
del d_list
```

Answer (score 0):

`temp_list = d_list` creates a *reference* so any changes in either list will be reflected in both  so that would definitely  not work.  `temp_list = d_list.copy()` creates a shallow copy which would work as would `temp_list = d_list[:]` but a better approach to avoid any copying at all would be to use `reversed` and just remove the elements from the list:

```
for item in reversed(d_list): 
    if item.get("weight", 0) > 180 or item.get("Name") == "Joe":
        d_list.remove(item)
        i -= 1
```

If you wanted to pop you could start at the end using a range in reverse:

```
for i in range(len(d_list) -1 , -1, - 1): 
    item = d_list[i]
    if item.get("weight", 0) > 180 or item.get("Name") == "Joe":   
        i -= 1
```

A third option is a [list comprehension](http://www.python-course.eu/list_comprehension.php) using `d_list[:]` to mutate the original object/list:

```
d_list[:]  = [d for d in d_list if  d.get("weight", 0) <= 180  and  d.get("Name")  != "Joe"]
```

Or combine it with a [generator expression](http://anandology.com/python-practice-book/iterators.html):

```
d_list[:] = (d for d in d_list if d.get("weight", 0) <= 180 and d.get("Name") != "Joe")
```

All approaches will give you the same output. Using `dict.get` instead of iterating over all the items is also a more efficient solution, we do two lookups per iteration instead of looking at all the keys and values in each dict.

Some timings using python3:

```
In [14]: %%timeit
d_list = [{'id': 1, 'Name': 'Hannah', 'weight': 150}, {'id': 2, 'Name': 'Andrew', 'weight': 200},
          {'id': 3, 'Name': 'Joe', 'weight': 180},
          {'id': 4, 'Name': 'Joe', 'weight': 180}, {'id': 5, 'Name': 'Steve', 'weight': 200},
          {'id': 6, 'Name': 'Joe', 'weight': 180},
          {'id': 7, 'Name': 'George', 'weight': 180}]
for item in reversed(d_list):    
    if item.get("weight", 0) > 180 or item.get("Name") == "Joe":
        d_list.remove(item)
   ....: 
100000 loops, best of 3: 4.35 µs per loop

In [15]: %%timeit
d_list = [{'id': 1, 'Name': 'Hannah', 'weight': 150}, {'id': 2, 'Name': 'Andrew', 'weight': 200},
          {'id': 3, 'Name': 'Joe', 'weight': 180},
          {'id': 4, 'Name': 'Joe', 'weight': 180}, {'id': 5, 'Name': 'Steve', 'weight': 200},
          {'id': 6, 'Name': 'Joe', 'weight': 180},
          {'id': 7, 'Name': 'George', 'weight': 180}]
for i in range(len(d_list) - 1, -1, - 1):  # may make a while loop
    item = d_list[i]
    if item.get("weight", 0) > 180 or item.get("Name") == "Joe":
        d_list.pop(i)
   ....: 
   ....:     
100000 loops, best of 3: 4.48 µs per loop

In [16]: %%timeit
   ....: d_list = [{'id': 1, 'Name': 'Hannah', 'weight': 150}, {'id': 2, 'Name': 'Andrew', 'weight': 200},
   ....:           {'id': 3, 'Name': 'Joe', 'weight': 180},
   ....:           {'id': 4, 'Name': 'Joe', 'weight': 180}, {'id': 5, 'Name': 'Steve', 'weight': 200},
   ....:           {'id': 6, 'Name': 'Joe', 'weight': 180},
   ....:           {'id': 7, 'Name': 'George', 'weight': 180}]
   ....: d_list[:] = (d for d in d_list if d.get("weight", 0) <= 180 and d.get("Name") != "Joe")
   ....: 
100000 loops, best of 3: 3.23 µs per loop

In [17]: %%timeit
d_list = [{'id': 1, 'Name': 'Hannah', 'weight': 150}, {'id': 2, 'Name': 'Andrew', 'weight': 200},
          {'id': 3, 'Name': 'Joe', 'weight': 180},
          {'id': 4, 'Name': 'Joe', 'weight': 180}, {'id': 5, 'Name': 'Steve', 'weight': 200},
          {'id': 6, 'Name': 'Joe', 'weight': 180},
          {'id': 7, 'Name': 'George', 'weight': 180}]
d_list[:] = [d for d in d_list if d.get("weight", 0) <= 180 and d.get("Name") != "Joe"]
   ....: 
100000 loops, best of 3: 2.98 µs per loop
```

So the list comp is the fastest followed by the gen exp. If you know the keys always exist then accessing with `d["weight"]` etc.. will also be faster again

Comment: What about using while loop instead of reversed for loop?  Any advantages either way?

Comment: @James, using reversed uses no extra space

Comment: Thanks it worked too. That should have been >= 180 but thats nick picking. LOL

Comment: @James, I was just testing you ;)

Comment: I have never seen that type of functions. I will have to figure it out but it works non the less and its nearly 50% faster.  Is there a name for that type of manipulations?

Comment: @James, the first is a list comprehension and the second a generator expression, I added two links. The `d_list[:]` lets us change the original object just like our explicit for loops, it just harnesses the efficiency of the list comprehension/ generator expression

Comment: Thanks, I will give them a look over.  Its a good day when you learn something and no one gets hurt! ;)

Comment: No prob, list comps and gen exps are a big part of python.